# Is the set of all irrational numbers countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Let us assume:
The countable union of countable sets is countable.
$\mathbb{R}$ is an uncountable set.
Any subset of a countable set is countable.

Let $\mathbb I = \{\, x\mid x\in \mathbb{R} \land x \notin \mathbb{Q} \,\}$

$\mathbb{I} \cup \mathbb{Q} = \mathbb{R}$ $\rightarrow$ The union of the rational and irrational real numbers is uncountable.

Let's show that $\mathbb{Z}$ is countable.
Define the function: 
$f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ as

$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{x}{2},  & \text{if $x$ is even} \\
\frac{1-x}{2}, & \text{if $x$ is odd}
\end{cases}$

Now we must show that the function $f$ is bijective.
$1-1$:
Assume $f(x)=f(y)$ for some $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$

Assume $x$ and $y$ are even, $f(x)=f(y) \rightarrow \frac{x}{2}=\frac{y}{2} \rightarrow x=y$

Assume $x$ and $y$ are odd, $f(x)=f(y) \rightarrow \frac{1-x}{2}=\frac{1-y}{2} \rightarrow x=y$

Now assume $x$ is odd and $y$ is even, $f(x)=f(y) \rightarrow \frac{1-x}{2}=\frac{y}{2} \rightarrow \frac{-x}{2}= \frac{y}{2}-\frac{1}{2} \rightarrow -x=y$
which cannot be true since $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$. Similar case for $x$ is even and $y$ is odd.
The last two show that $x$ and $y$ must have the same parity.
So, for all possible cases, $f(x)=f(y) \rightarrow x=y$ which shows that $f$ is $1-1$.

Onto:
Suppose $w \in \mathbb{Z}$.
If $w \gt0$, then $2w$ is even and $f(2w)=\frac{2w}{2}=w$.
If $w \leq0$, then $1-2w$ is odd and $f(1-2w)=\frac{1-(1-2w)}{2}=w$.
In both cases, $w\in Rng(f) \rightarrow f$ maps onto $\mathbb{Z}$.

This implies that $\mathbb{Z}\approx \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ is countable.

Now that we know that $\mathbb{Z}$ is countable, we can show that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable.

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define $A_n$ to be the set

$A_n = \{\, \frac{m}{n}\mid m\in \mathbb{Z} \,\}$

Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is countable, each $A_n$ is countable.

So, $\forall q \in \mathbb{Q}, \exists n \in \mathbb{N} \mid q \in \mathbb{N}$

So, $\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n =\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ is countable.

Since, $\mathbb{I} \cup \mathbb{Q} = \mathbb{R}$, then $\mathbb{I}$ must be uncountable.

So, the set of irrational reals is not countable.

I am looking for input on this proof for a class.

Comment: You probably want to change the title to something that reflects the content of the question. You have 140 characters. Use them! (Also, no, the irrational numbers are *not* a countable set.)

Comment: Ok, so proof that the set of irrational numbers is uncountable?

Comment: $\Bbb Q$ is _not_ a subset of $\Bbb Z$. Thus you have not shown that $\Bbb Q$ is countable.

Comment: In general we need the Axiom of Choice (AC) (or one of its corollaries, called Countable Choice) to prove that a countable union of countable sets is uncountable.  For some specific cases, such as $\mathbb Q, $ we do not need AC.

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely not true that $\Bbb Q\subset\Bbb Z$. You will have to show that $\Bbb Q$ is countable to prove this result. One way you can do that is to define the sets
$$
A_n = \{\:n/k : \text{$k$ is a nonzero integer}\:\},\qquad\text{where $n\in\Bbb Z_{\ge0}$,}
$$
each of which is countable. Then $\bigcup_n A_n$ is the countable union of countable sets and is equal to $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Dang, thank you both. Will work on it. I can't believe I made that mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong, because it is not true that $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb Z$. Acutally, $\mathbb{Q}\supset\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

To enumerate the rationals, enumerate every pair $(p,q)$ with $p,q\in\mathbb Z$ (this can be done by spiraling around the origin), simplify the fraction$\dfrac pq$, and assign it a new natural unless it has already been seen.

The exhaustive enumeration of $(p,q)$ guarantees that every fraction is listed, hence every rational. And the rejection of duplicates guarantees a bijection.

Answer (score 0):

You can also show directly that $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ is uncountable, by a variant of Cantor's diagonal argument:

Suppose $f$ is a function $\mathbb N\to\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$. We can then find an irrational number that is not in the range of $f$:

We choose the $k$th decimal of the output number such that

- It is either $2$ or $3$ when $k$ is a perfect square.
- It is either $4$ or $5$ when $k$ is *not* a perfect square.
- In any case, it is different from the $k$th decimal of $f(k)$.

The two first rules make sure that the sequence of decimals can never repeat, and therefore the resulting number is irrational.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb R $ is uncountable.   $\mathbb Q $ is countable. Thus $\mathbb R-\mathbb Q $ is uncountable.   (The union of two countable sets is countable. )

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use cardinal arithmetic:

First, note that the rationals are countable because the map $(m,n)\mapsto 2^m\cdot 3^n$ from $\mathbb Q\subset \mathbb N\times \mathbb N$ is injective.

Then, note that $\mathbb R$ is the $\textit{disjoint}$ union of $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb I$. Therefore, $\mathfrak c=|\mathbb R|=|\mathbb Q\cup\mathbb I|=\omega +|\mathbb I|,$ which shows that $|\mathbb I|>\omega$ because if not we would have $\mathfrak c=\omega +|\mathbb I| =\omega$ which is impossible. Thus $\mathbb I$ is uncountable.

Comment: How do you know that $f(m,n) = 2^m3^n$ is injective?

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist: uniqueness of prime factorization